# JXBrowser required to be open to run automated tests using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jxbrowser

I have been able to successfully connect to a JXBrowser session using the ChromeDriver by specifying the --remote-debugging-port as described in the documentation.  The issue I have with this is this implementation requires the JXBrowser to be opened before each test is started.  I have attempted to workaround this by specifying a "jxbrowser.exe" as the chrome binary, which does get the browser to start automatically. The WebDriver cannot communicate with the browser in this scenario though since the ChromeDriver creates a random port each time a session is created, which will almost always be different than the port defined in the --remote-debugging-port property.

I have tested the same scenario with a standard Chromium Embedded Framework client, and specifying a debugging-port is not required, thus works as expected.  Defining the port on the ChromeDriver side is not supported, so is there a way to either specify a debugging-port range or open it entirely as the CEF client has?

Comment: I think we need to enable in-process DevTools in JxBrowser to let WebDriver works with JxBrowser without necessary of providing --remote-debugging-port property. We do have this feature request in our product backlog. It will be implemented in one of the next versions.